# How to give notification on icon

Tags: iphone, ios4

How can I add some kind of notification on an application icon displayed on the springboard?

Like it can be seen on messenger icons showing a number with red color on it once new messages are received.

Answer (score 2):

[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;